# Adding an Image in xaml code?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

How can I add an image to my program in XAML?

I want to display the 'no.png' image on my application. Also,

[image]

I need both yes and no to appear in the same place. My plan was to set them both to hidden and display them only when necessary. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the two png's in a StackPanel and programatically control their Visibility setting.

Answer (score 3):

yep just add the image xaml, and either use visual state manager, behaviours or code behind to switch the visibility

```
    <Image Source="/Background.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Image Source="/Background.png" Visibility="Visible"/>
```